# Search Bar in a TableView with Core Data (using Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, tableview, uisearchbar

I am making a **TableViewController** with Core Data. In fact the users can add new items to the Table View and these items are saved in **Core Data**. Everything has worked fine but when I add a **Search Bar** I'm blocked.

I added a Search Bar but this function bellow create an error when I run the app in the simulator.

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController,)
{
    filteredTableData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text)
    let array = (series as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)
    filteredTableData = array as! [String]

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

The error I get is " *terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException* "

PS : I use Xcode 6.3.2 and all the code is in Swift.

Comment: Use an  [exception breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html), it might help you understand what's the problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
    var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Serie")
    filteredTableData.removeAll(keepCapacity: false)
    let searchPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.infos CONTAINS[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text)
    let array = (series as NSArray).filteredArrayUsingPredicate(searchPredicate)

    for item in array
    {
        let infoString = item.infos
        filteredTableData.append(infoString)
    }

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! You made my day ;)

Comment: Note that on larger data sets it's not always a good idea to search and update your UI in `updateSearchResultsForSearchController`.